# Redirect User to Another Server on Azure Service Down?

Tags: azure

We are using Azure Cloud Service for our Project. Once in a week for maintenance reason we need to Stop our Cloud Service for about 30 Minutes. Now here we want to implement some logic that if Cloud Service is down and people got 504 (Gateway Timeout), they will automatically redirected to some other Url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="http://yourdomain.com/errors/Error.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
       <error redirect="http://yourdomain.com/errors/504.aspx" statusCode="504" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

another option is using url rewrite:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SiteDown" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="504" statusReason="Down for maintenance" statusDescription="will be back up soon" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```